# How to count the number of symbolic variables in an equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, equation, symbolic-math

Suppose I have three equations like `[x1+x2+x3, -x1, x1+x2+1]`.

Is there any function in MATLAB by which I can count the number of symbolic variables of each of these equations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the **total** number of variables, you can use [`symvar`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html) as follows:

```
>> syms x1 x2 x3                  % define symbolic variables
>> y = [x1+x2+x3, -x1, x1+x2+1]   % define symbolic equation
>> numel(symvar(y))               % get number of sumbolic variables
ans =
     3
```

To obtain the number of variables of **each** equation, you can use the following, as suggested by [@SardarUsama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698672/sardar-usama):

```
>> arrayfun(@(t) numel(symvar(t)), y)
ans =
     3     1     2
```

This loops over the equations and gets the number of variables of each.

Comment: I interpreted the question as number of variables in *each* equation are required to be found separately. `cellfun(@(k) numel(symvar(k)),children(y))` or I am mistaken

Comment: @SardarUsama You are totally right. I misread the question. Please post that yourself

Comment: I think you should include that in your answer because all I am suggesting is just a loop in your answer. My first comment is what I  initially thought. It would be simpler with: `arrayfun(@(k)  numel(symvar(k)), y)`

Comment: @SardarUsama Done. Thanks!